# Not able to append data to a file using php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I am in the learning process.
I tried writing data to a file and it worked.

Now i tried adding data added by the user to a file in append mode, I have not idea why its not working out.

Code :

```
<?php

if(isset($name)){
    $name=$_POST['data'];
    if (!empty($name)) {
        $handle=fopen("Name.txt", 'a');
        fwrite($handle, $name."\n");
        fclose($handle);
        echo "Added to file sucessfully !";
    }else{
        echo "Please enter a name in the text box !";
    }
}


?>
<form action="nwfile.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="data">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I am not able to find any issue with my code , but I also have no idea why no data is getting written in the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this use `if(isset($_POST['data'])){`

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
    $name=$_POST['data'];
    if (!empty($name)) {
        $handle=fopen("Name.txt", 'a');
        fwrite($handle, $name."\n");
        fclose($handle);
        echo "Added to file sucessfully !";
    }else{
        echo "Please enter a name in the text box !";
    }
}


?>
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="data">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You might want to add an explanation rather than just code.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I would assume so.  An answer without context isn't a very good answer.  It'd be like a teacher showing the code but not how they got there, how useful would that education be?

Comment: @OsamaJetawe: I didn't downvoted, downvote was removed as I see, but you should always add an explanation. The second reason could be that your answer is the same as mine one, and have no additional value. Probably.

Comment: Thank You @panther. i will keep it up

Answer (score 1):

The first condition on line 3 is `false`, variable `$name` doesn't exist yet - you set it up on next line.

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {
    ...
}
```